# java обработчик событий клавиатуры lwjgl

Tags: java, разработка-игр, lwjgl

слушатель в библиотеке lwjgl устроен так:

```
class keyboard extends GLFWKeyCallback {
     public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
     }
}
```

Этот слушатель вызывается в 3 случаях если клавиша была нажата, если клавиша была зажата, если клавишу отпустили.

но вот незадача между только нажата и зажата проходит 1 секунда.

запуская в цикле while в методе update(60 обновлений в сек) не получается выделить нажатие(нажатие это когда метод срабатывает 1 раз)

```
protected void update() {
    if(Input.isKeyPress(GLFW_KEY_ENTER))
        button.create();
}
```

вот метод Input

```
public class Input extends GLFWKeyCallback {

    private static boolean[] keys = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];

    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
    }

    public static boolean isKeyPress(int key) {
        return ???????????????????????????????????????????????????;
    }

    public static boolean isKeyRepeat(int key) {
        return keys[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067791/lwjgl-holding-a-key-pressed

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев это реализация в старой lwjgl 2.x в lwjgl 3 этого  Keyboard нет.

Answer (score 0):

Чем вас не устраивает библиотека `AWT`? Можно использовать метод [`addKeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.accessibility/com/sun/java/accessibility/util/AWTEventMonitor.html#addKeyListener(java.awt.event.KeyListener)) из класса `AWTEventMonitor`:

```java
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        controller.keyPressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        controller.keyReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        controller.keyTyped(e);
    }
});
```